# Angular Material mat-option alternative retrieving values

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a following example

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let example of examples" [value]="example.Id">{{example Description}}</mat-option>
```

...where example is an int/string object.

All good. Certain logic requires example.Id to be passed to component hence this is set as the value.

However on `this.form.value` I want the description to be passed automatically instead as value.

What are my options?

Comment: [value]="example" try this

Comment: No, because as I explained I need the ID passed for certain scenarios that drive other logic.

Comment: you want to get example object when you submit the form right?

Comment: Only description when submitting.

Comment: I think I will have to go with [value]="example" and then dig deeper to get the ID as you suggested... but then my Json will look ugly because on submit it will contain both int/string for each control.
Ahh welll...

Answer (score 0):

just use the value in brackets {{example.description}}, or what is the problem ?

Comment: On submit button I call this.form.value to fetch all the values from multiple controls and since it grabs [value]="example.Id, but I need description instead without tweaking the code.Using value in brackets would populate the dropdown with integers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities

- You have an example Object with `{id: number, description: string}` then you cann pass the description easy with `{{example.description}}`.
- You can call a Method fo get the Description like that:`<mat-option *ngFor="let example of examples" [value]="example.Id">{{getDescription(example.Id)}}</mat-option>`

Comment: Simon... I didn't make myself clear I think... There was a typo in my OP and yes, I use {{example.description}}. This is fine an working so I gt my dropdowns populated accordignly, and showing on the screen... Now.. 
1) for some screen logic I need to get the ID (integer) passed to the component which is easy since the ID is set in the html as the control's value:
this.createRequestForm.get('myControl').valueChanges
            .subscribe(value => {
2) When I am all done I want to harvest all the values from the controls but this time I want passed Description instead of ID

Comment: Why do you not put the description as value?

Comment: Because then I cant get the ID out of the selected item that needs passed to other functions.